# UITableView return empty cell swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

in my `CellForrowAtIndex` I am doing like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HomeCell") as! HomeNewsCellTableViewCell!

    if cell == nil
   {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HomeNewsCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")
       // tblNews.registerClass(HomeNewsCellTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")

        cell = HomeNewsCellTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")

    }

    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.imgVwThumb?.image = UIImage(named: "SplashLogo")
    cell.imgVwThumb?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

and the rest of the code is assigning values to the cell labels.
But in 7th cell I am getting an empty cell.
`

```
cell1


cell2

cell3
empty
cell4
```

like this. What is the reason for this? How can I solve this?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: How did you printed out that values?

Comment: no I just gave an example, 1st 3 cell are coming  but the 4th one is an empty cell then rest of the cells are loading normally

Comment: Perhaps not the solution to your issue but you should call tableView.registerNib once in e.g viewDidLoad not inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Yeah, definitely call registerNib in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks,, :) That solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register cell nib in viewDidLoad() not in CellForRow(). I'm changing the code, this will work for you.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       (yourTableViewReference).registerNib(UINib(nibName:"HomeNewsCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HomeCell") as! HomeNewsCellTableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.imgVwThumb?.image = UIImage(named: "SplashLogo")
    cell.imgVwThumb?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    return cell
}
```